# Music loses quality when playing at the same time

Tags: windows, audio, music, gaming, radio

well the problem is that when i play a steam game for example, i usually listen to the radio, i use VLC for this, it works perfectly until i open the game. When i open the game apparently looks like the game has higher preference or something and the radio sound sounds really bad, with interferences or something, if i mute the game it sounds perfectly. I use headphones and what i want if possible, is to hear both game and radio without losing quality, any idea? Thanks

P.D. My OS is Windows 10

Comment: Do you get the same loss in quality when not using headphones?

Comment: Yes, same problem when using speakers

Comment: Describe the quality loss. Does it begin to play intermittently? Do you hear static? Is the volume fluctuating? Volume fluctuation when multiple sources are trying to output at once is a common issue, but is certainly different from a loss of quality..

Comment: It's like the sound goes back and forth, like if when the game has a high-pitched sound it lowers the volume of the radio, and then the radio volume rise again

Comment: @Javi This should then be labeled as a volume attenuation problem (commonly referred to as "ducking"), not as a loss of quality. This most commonly happens when Windows detects that input (from your microphone) could be sent to an application (common with games, VoIP, ect). Start by going into Control Panel - Sounds -> Communications (tab) and selecting `Do nothing` (see "DDE" for more `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316773(v=vs.85).aspx`). Also be sure to test for results with other communication applications off (eg Skype).

Comment: I set it on the "Do nothing" and skype sounds better know, but my the radio-game problem is not solved yet

Comment: Turn Skype off when testing to isolate the problem. The volume attenuation may be controlled by your game or game provider.

Comment: I have tried with skype off and nothing changes